# How do I flatMap two singles?

Tags: ios, swift, observable, rx-swift, flatmap

I have an `observable` that looks like this:

```
func getParameters() -> Single<[ParameterModel]?> {
    do {
        loading.accept(allParameters.isEmpty)
        return try parameterService.getParameters()
            .do(onSuccess: { [weak self] parameters in
                self?.loading.accept(false)
                self?.content.accept(parameters?.compactMap { $0 }
                                                .compactMap { TechnicianParameterTableViewCellViewModel(parameter: $0) } ?? [])
            })
    } catch { return Single.error(error) }
}
```

The important part is where it `compactMaps` into a `cell`. This works as expected. But I also have another observable that looks like this:

```
func getSingleOrDoubleDoor() -> Single<SingleOrDoubleDoor?> { //SingleOrDoubleDoor is an enum
    do {
        return try parameterService.getSingleOrDoubleDoor()
    } catch {
        return Single.error(error)
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to sort of merge `getSingleOrDoubleDoor()` into `getParameters()` so that I can access the values of both `observables` in `onSuccess`. I want to use the result sort of like this:

```
.compactMap { TechnicianParameterTableViewCellViewModel(parameter: $0, isSingleOrDouble: $1) } ?? [])
```

Not being an expert on `Rx` I still assume that this is done using `.flatMap{}`. Sort of like:

```
...return try parameterService.getParameters().flatMap { _ in getSingleOrDoubleDoor() }...
```

But this gives me an error:

> > Cannot convert value of type '([ParameterModel]?) -> Single<SingleOrDoubleDoor?>' (aka '(Optional<Array>) -> PrimitiveSequence<SingleTrait, Optional>') to expected argument type '([ParameterModel]?) throws -> PrimitiveSequence<SingleTrait, [ParameterModel]?>'

Tried changing the return expression but it still wouldn't take. Not sure how to make this happen.

Comment: This article might help: [Recipes for Combining Observables in RxSwift](https://danielt1263.medium.com/recipes-for-combining-observables-in-rxswift-ec4f8157265f)

Comment: Thaks, I'll make sure to check it out!

Answer (score 1):

Since your methods don't accept parameters, I'll assume they don't depend on each other. If so, you should use the `zip` method like this:

```
Single
   .zip(getParameters(), getSingleOrDoubleDoor())
   .compactMap { TechnicianParameterTableViewCellViewModel(parameter: $0, isSingleOrDouble: $1) } ?? [])
```

The zip method will trigger the compactMap when both methods return a value. `Flatmap` has a different purpose, it is usually used when we need to call methods sequentially, meaning the next call needs data from the previous one.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for clearing that up. Don't think zip will do it though since it requires both functions to have the same amount of elements. Superfluous elements will disappear.

Comment: @JoakimSjöstedt what do you mean by elements and superfluous elements?

Comment: @JoakimSjöstedt both `getParameters()` and `getSingleOrDoubleDoor()` emit a single element. I.E. "the same amount of elements."

Comment: @Daniel T. Ah, yes, my bad, I was thinking about it in the wrong way. Thanks!